# How should I understand the ありそうなものだったが?

Tags: phrases, sentence

> だが、タイミングの悪いことに、お菓子の類が全てなくなってしまっていた。琴里の部屋に行けばチュッパチャプスのストックくらいは**ありそうなものだったが**、それに手を出そうものなら、あとでどんな報復が待っているかわからなかった。

Context: 士道’s friend played “trick or treat” with him but 士道 didn’t have any candies at that time.

Hi. How should I parse or understand the bold part? I know if 士道 went to 琴里’s room he would find some candies. But isn’t it enough to just say ありそうだったが (it seems there are some candies, but...)?

By the way, why is ものだったが rather than ものだが used here?

Thank you.

Comment: Because the past tense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **ストックはある**: There is a stock (of Chupa Chups).
- **ストックくらいはある**: There is at least a stock.
- **ストックくらいはありそう**: There seems to be at least a stock.
- **ストックくらいはありそうなものだ**: (I think) there has to be at least a stock.
- **ストックくらいはありそうなものだった**: (I thought) there had to be at least a stock.

The tricky part should be ものだ, which has [several meanings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010). Here, this ものだ describes his conjecture based on 琴里's general tendency. ～そうなものだ is a set phrase used when something doesn't meet your natural expectation. See: [Using もの at the end of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29084/5010)

> - このくらい簡単に出来そうなものだが、どうしても出来ない。
> - ここで待機を命じられているが、することがないので家に帰ってもよさそうなものだ。