# Strange usage of というもの

Tags: grammar

**I need help understanding というもの in the sentence 貴方一人を御し得ないようでは私の器も知れるというもの.**

I am reading Fate/Stay Night: Unlimited Blade Works and one of the servants "Caster", is going to use her blade to take control of another servant. 
Since he is a traitor she is not sure if it would be the best move and she is hesitating on whether or not to use the blade.
He told her that he could betray her, but since the conditions are in her favour, as long as Caster has the upper hand he will not do so.

Her response:

> 「令呪とは、裏切り者を罰する為にある、でしょう？
>   ……いいわ。**貴方一人を御し得ないようでは私の器も知れるというもの。**
>   もとより貴方の“宝具”には興味があった事だし、思惑にはまってあげましょう」

My understanding:

> - Verb-ますstem + 得ない = Cannot Verb.
> - 貴方一人を御し得ない =I cannot control only you
> - ようでは = If [with negative result]

My translation:

> Command seals are there in order to punish traitors, right?
>   Ok. If I can't control you alone, you will know my (tool, device which in this context is a) blade.
>   From the beginning I had an interest in your "Noble Phantasm", I will go on with your intention."

Fan Translation:

> "The Command Spell is there to punish the betrayer, right?
>   …All right. I shall prove to the world that I am great enough to take you in.
>   I am interested in your Noble Phantasm, so I will follow your plan."

**How does というもの add on to the nuance of the sentence?**

Comment: Hi. Your question was not well received probably due to a lack of focus on the question and having a weak link between what you have put in effort in, and what you were trying to find out. I have added a question explicitly in an attempt to clarify the question. If you feel that your intention was lost, please rollback the edit or edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's some ancient accent invented (or adapted?) by the author, you will never hear any real person say that. "というもの" here is close to "だもの" or "ですもの" or "ということだけ", which emphasizes that the person is very confident about what he / she said.

But "器" in this sentence doesn't mean "device", in the common phrase "器が知れる" it means one's power / caliber / capacity to control and lead others.

Comment: Thank you.
Could you help me with a translation to better understand the meaning of the complete sentence?

Comment: @Splikie The fan translation is a little bit too folksy but in general quite great. The only part not so perfect is the last sentence "I will follow your plan". "思惑にはまってあげましょう" shows that caster knows it may be a trap ("はまる" is almost a verb used exclusively on traps or trap-like events) but she doesn't care, she thought she can handle it.

Comment: I still do not understand why the author used "貴方一人を御し得ないようでは" since what follows it is not a negative event.  
貴方一人を御し得ないようでは=If can't control even you alone
私の器も知れるというもの=My caliber will be known
Am I translating anything wrong?

Comment: The line does sound pompous and 中二病-like, but I don't think it was invented by the author. Many characters in fiction speak in this way.

Comment: @Splikie "私の器も知れるというもの" is a negative phrase, it means "that's my limit of .." or "... is no better than that". For example "高が知れる" doesn't mean "knowing the height" but "It's just that high / of no importance".

Comment: @zakyggaps
I see. So I understand it this way:" If I can't even control you alone, it means my power is not that great". or Am I completely off?

Comment: @Splikie That's right. I'm sorry for my poor English skills.

Comment: Don't worry, they are fine. It was the translation that misguided me. Thank you

Comment: The entire first paragraph makes no sense.  This use of 「～～というもの」 is quite common indeed.  And it is current!

Comment: @l'électeur It's common in 「～というもの(の)」 (the last の is optional) and 「～という者{もの}/物{もの}」 but not in this flavor.

Comment: The というもの here doesn't mean だもの, ですもの or ということだけ. It means 「というもの**だ** 。」 こういう使い方です→　http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%94%B2%E6%96%90%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0　あるいは、これが参考になるかも→ http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28872/how-to-parse-%E8%A6%AA%E3%82%82%E8%BE%9E%E6%9B%B8%E3%82%92%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0/30122

Answer (score 3):

That …というもの（だ） means that it's natural for everyone to consider it that way. I'd translate it to "Without being able to control you alone, that **should** be the limit of my capability".