# Difference between ものだ and というものだ

Tags: grammar, nuances

> 人気者がそろっているというだけで、華やいだかんじになる**というものだ**。
>   Simply having popular people around makes for a cheerful feeling.

I think the ものだ used here is number 2) from [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43127/7944). Please correct me if I'm wrong. I was wondering what additional nuance という adds. Can it be omitted without changing the meaning?

I guess the same question can apply to the first half of the sentence (というだけで). Do the two というs pair up somehow?

Comment: It's mean "generally " or sometimes used 私は「なになに」というものだ。

Comment: Related: The “ってもんだ” section of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29018/888

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 人気者がそろっているだけで、華やいだかんじに**なるものだ**。
>
> Simply having popular people around **makes** for a cheerful feeling.
>
> 人気者がそろっているというだけで、華やいだかんじに**なるというものだ。**
>
> Simply having popular people around **would make** for a cheerful feeling.

In Japanese, the both sentences mean almost the same, but the latter sounds softer, milder, or more indirect.

The two という in the former half and in the latter half sentence are functioning  in the same way.

Comment: Probably, という connotes 'for example'...