# What would be the function of the というものだ in this context?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

> 一体、士道や琴里にどんな狙いがあるかわからなかったが、それが七罪にとって不利益になるものであろうことは想像に難くなかった。きっと何らかの方法で七罪に復讐するつもりに決まっているのだ。それこそ、肥え太らせてから食べてしまうつもりかもしれない。それならば、七罪にこんなに美味しいご飯を与える意味もわかる**というものだ**。

Hi. What would be the function of the というものだ?
Does it mean “something like” as explained in this link?
https://japanese.upstory.biz/archives/4999

Or it has some other functions?

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sentence-end ものだ has many functions, but in your case it adds the nuance of "that's the way it is" with a bit of emotion. Here it is marking the natural conclusion based on the mentioned idea (肥え太らせてから食べてしまうつもり).

- [Meaning of the phase: 筋ってもん](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74147/5010)

  > it’s basically a masculine-ish way of giving a “that’s the way things are” sort of finality to your sentence.
- [How to parse 親も辞書を買ってやったかいがあるってもんだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28872/5010)

  > Adding it to a phrase can have the effect of turning a singular event into a generalized phenomenon.
- [why ひどい神もいたもんだ　means "that's a mean god"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53893/5010)

  > this type of ものだ carries the sense of exclamation or surprise.
- [Difference between ものだ and というものだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46619/5010)
- [The meanings of ものだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010)

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn’t realize that the というものだ was just a variant of ものだ.

Comment: Hi. Can we omit the という and just use ものだ in this context?

Comment: @chinoalpha No, that という is mandatory.

Comment: Thank you. But why? I checked the thread “difference between ものだ and というものだ” and it says the という version just sounds softer, milder, or more indirect.

Comment: @chinoalpha In your example you cannot use ものだ because ご飯を与える意味もわかる itself is not a "general" fact. But in a sentence like 親になってこそ親の気持ちがわかるものだ, ものだ and というものだ are interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you again. I got it.