# Understanding 可能形+もの

Tags: grammar

> 「……折紙さんはもう除隊しやがってますし、真那は裏切り同然の形でDEMを出奔していやがります。正面から行って入れてもらえる**ものですか**ね？」

The speaker (真那) and her friend (折紙) wanted to enter a military base that they used to belong to. The speaker was asking 折紙 whether they could enter it from the front gate.

Can I understand the ものですか as “Is that the way... (in general)”, as in this link?
[https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/understanding-なんで-もんかね](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/understanding-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7-%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AD)

If not, what usage is this もの?