# もの in this sentence

Tags: grammar

日本人は外来語なしで話ができる**もの**なんでしょうか?

how would it change if just said できますか or できるんでしょうか?

what does the もの imply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ["ものだ for general tendency/fact"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82294/5010) but in a question form. It adds a sense of "Is it generally the case that...?" or "Is it how things normally work...?"

1. …できますか: a plain question
2. …できるのですか: seeking explanation
3. …できるものなのですか: seeking explanation as a general fact

In your case, since the subject of the sentence is explicitly 日本人 in general, the difference between 2 and 3 is small. But when the subject is not present, the implied subject may change due to this ものだ/ものか.

- え、寿司を手で食べるんですか？
  Oh, are you eating sushi with your hands?
- え、寿司を手で食べる**もの**なんですか？
  Oh, do people (in general) eat sushi with their hands?