# Meaning of the phase: 筋ってもんだ

Tags: formal-nouns

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a grasp of 筋ってもん (sujitte mon) and what it's supposed to convey.  Does it possibly have kind of declarative function for whatever precedes it?

Examples include:

> 俺の通すべき[筋]{すじ}ってもんだ

and

> 生身でもがくのが筋ってもんだ

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a little more context telling us what you think it means, and why you struggle with your assumed meaning?

Comment: @ajsmart I don't really have an assumed meaning.

Comment: If that's the case, you should know that translation requests are considered off-topic.  To avoid having the question closed as such, please include evidence of your research in the body of the question.  See: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/22352

Comment: Your first example is an inversion of the idiom 筋を通す, which has its own unique meaning. The latter is a usage of 〜するのが筋だ, which has a separate meaning. ってもん is pretty unrelated and is its own grammar point. Maybe you could focus your question on just one of these?

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie Then the latter, how it relates to doing something.

Comment: Related (regarding ってもんだ): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29018/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the core of your confusion comes from not knowing a meaning of 筋{すじ} which is applicable in both of your sentences; that is:

> ❺ 物事の論理的な流れ。道理。
>   「➖の通った話」
>   <sub>明鏡国語辞典　第二版</sub>

This usage of 筋 is pretty idiomatic and mostly found in the expressions 筋が通る or 筋を通す, which you should be able to look up directly.

「〜するのが筋だ」 stems from that usage and basically means that 〜 is the reasonable, logical, right, or natural thing to do.

The ってもんだ is best explained in detail elsewhere (see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28872/how-to-parse-%E8%A6%AA%E3%82%82%E8%BE%9E%E6%9B%B8%E3%82%92%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0/29018#29018), h/t Chocolate for finding that), but it’s basically a masculine-ish way of giving a “that’s the way things are” sort of finality to your sentence. Overall, I would say that 筋ってもんだ is not so common a collocation to be able to treat it as a single unit, so it is likely better to consider them separately.